# How to optimize Pandas group by +- margin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to optimize my code where Group by +- margin using python. I want to group my Dataframe composed of 2 columns ['1', '2'] based on a margin +-1 (1) and +-10 (2)
For example, a really simplified overlook

```
[[273, 10],[274, 14],[275, 15]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[273, 10],[274, 14]],[[274, 14],[275, 15]]
```

My data is much more complex with nearly 1 million data points looking like this 652.125454455

This kind of code for example take me for ever, with no results

```
a = np.random.uniform(low=300, high=1800, size=(300000,))
b = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=7200, size=(300000,))
print("Random numbers were created")
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': a, '2':b})
df['id'] = df.index
1_MARGIN = 1
2_MARGIN = 10

tic = time.time()

group = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    filtered_df = df[(row['1'] - 1_MARGIN < df['1']) & (df['1'] < row['1'] + 1_MARGIN) & 
                     (row['2'] - 2_MARGIN < df['2']) & (df['2'] < row['2'] + 2_MARGIN)]
    group.append(filtered_df[['id', '1']].values.tolist())

toc = time.time()
print(f"for loop: {str(1000*(toc-tic))} ms")
```

I also tried

```
data = df.groupby('1')['2'].apply(list).reset_index(name='irt')
```

but in this case there is no margin

Comment: I saw that you posted this question a week ago but wanted to optimize it, Can you please test the two solutions I posted and see which one is faster? On my PC the second one is much faster, but on your hardware would be a more accurate benchmark

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to understand what you wanted and I arrived at a very slow solution but at least it's a solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.random.uniform(low=300, high=1800, size=(300000,))
b = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=7200, size=(300000,))
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': a, '2':b})
dfbl1=np.sort(df['1'].apply(int).unique())
dfbl2=np.sort(df['2'].apply(int).unique())
MARGIN1 = 1
MARGIN2 = 10
marg1array=np.array(range(dfbl1[0],dfbl1[-1],MARGIN1))
marg2array=np.array(range(dfbl2[0],dfbl2[-1],MARGIN2))
a=time.perf_counter()
groupmarg1=[]
groupmarg2=[]
for low,upper in zip(marg1array[:-1],marg1array[1:]):
    for low2,upper2 in zip(marg2array[:-1],marg2array[1:]):
        groupmarg1.append(df.loc[(df['1']>low) & (df['1']<upper)&(df['2']>low2) & (df['2']<upper2)].values.tolist())

print(time.perf_counter()-a)
```

I also tried to do each loop seperately and intersect them which should be faster but since we're storing .values.tolist() I couldn't figure out a faster way than below.

```
a=time.perf_counter()
groupmarg1=[]
groupmarg2=[]
for low,upper in zip(marg1array[:-1],marg1array[1:]):
    groupmarg1.append(df.loc[(df['1']>low) & (df['1']<upper)])    
newgroup=[]
for subgroup in groupmarg1:
    for low2,upper2 in zip(marg2array[:-1],marg2array[1:]):
        newgroup.append(subgroup.loc[(subgroup['2']>low2) & (subgroup['2']<upper2)].values.tolist())
print(time.perf_counter()-a)
```

which runs in ~9mins on my machine.
Oh and you need to filter out the empty dataframes, and if you want them as values.tolist() you can do it while filtering like this

```
gr2=[grp.values.tolist() for grp in newgroup if not grp.empty]
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion but this still does not work for me because I might have cases with for example [[1, 252.124, 56.337', '2, 265.132, 98.582', '3, 266.140, -2.2177391052246094', '4, 266.128, 98.010'] what is most important is [1],[2,5][3],[4] but I didn't get this results using ur algorithm I really do not know why.